# Essential geometric morphism seen topologically

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topos-theory

I know that any geometric morphism between toposes of sheaves on spaces $f^*\colon Sh(X)\leftrightarrows Sh(Y)\colon f_*$ comes from a continuous map $f\colon X\to Y$. But what does it mean for $f$ the fact that $(f^*,f_*)$ is essential? I can't find anything more than the page of nlab, where the condition is linked to "connectedness" of the spaces. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism

An interesting [topic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123005/essential-geometric-morphisms-on-the-etale-site) on MO shows that
- If I consider an etale morphism on the etale site of schemes, then it induces an essential geometric morphism;
- I think the same holds in the case of the etale site of topological spaces.

So, is there a pattern?

Comment: Are you looking for some intuition behind the definition or the definition itself? The nlab page seems to give a nice rigorous definition: $(f^*, f_*)$ is essential if $f^*$ has a left adjoint. A geometric morphism automatically satisfies $f^*$ preserves finite limits. The adjective "essential" upgrades it to the requirement that $f^*$ preserves all small limits (this is an equivalent definition by the Adjoint Functor Theorem).

Comment: :) Not at all, I don't have any problem with the definition of essential geometric morphism; I can even produce lots of examples (those mentioned before, the essential geometric morphism induced between the toposes of $G$-objects...).

The question is the following: given that *any* geometric morphism between toposes Sh(X) -> Sh(Y) comes from a ctns map X -> Y, the purely categorical property of being essential must translate into a topological property. What is this property?

Comment: Oh. I see. Interesting.

Comment: Being essential is a weak form of other conditions. For example, a locally connected geometric morphism is essential but not vice versa. Being locally connected is a condition that can be phrased topologically: see [Butz and Moerdijk, _Representing topoi by groupoids_].

Answer (score 1):

To collect some more references into a partial answer:

- For $Y = \operatorname{pt}$ and in the setting of $\infty$-topoi, Lurie shows [HA, A.1.8] that this is equivalent to $X$ being *locally of constant shape*, i.e. for every $\mathscr F \in \mathbf{Sh}(X)$, the terminal morphism of $\infty$-topoi $\pi \colon \mathbf{Sh}(X)_{/\mathscr F} \to \mathscr S$ has the property that $\pi_*\pi^*$ preserves (small) limits (roughly speaking, cohomology of constant abelian sheaves commutes with limits on every open $U \subseteq X$). Paracompact CW complexes are given as an example.
- Conversely, if $X = \{y\}$ is a point, then $f \colon \{y\} \to Y$ gives an essential geometric morphism if and only if there is a smallest neighbourhood containing $y$ [SGA 4.1, Exp. IV, §7.6]. For closed points this means that $y$ is isolated, but also any point in a finite $T_0$ space has this property (the smallest open is the cosieve $Y_{\geq y}$ of points specialising to $y$).

Answer (score 0):

This is Zhen Lin's comment turned into an answer. The following can be found in  the article [Representing topoi by topological groupoids](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404997001072) by Carsten Butz and Ieke Moerdijk, see Section 3.

**Definition:** A continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$ of topological spaces is called *locally connected* if it is an open map, and $X$ can be covered by open subspaces $\{U_\alpha\}$ such that the fibers $f^{-1}(y) \cap U_{\alpha}$ of the restriction $f\vert_{U_{\alpha}}\colon U_{\alpha} \to Y$ are either empty or connected.

**Proposition:** If $f\colon X \to Y$ is locally connected, then the induced map of topoi $f^*\colon Sh(X)\leftrightarrows Sh(Y)\colon f_*$ is locally connected, and thus in particular essential.